# Why does ILSpy generate a source even though it was developed with C ++ Windows Application?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, obfuscation

Why does ILSpy generate a source even though it was developed with C ++ Windows Application?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NT5S.jpg
developing it with C ++↑

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Ihu.jpg)

↑In order not to display like Noah CSGO?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you've missed the fact, that you can write in C++ and compile it into MSIL assembly and run that as .net managed code.

Go and see - in Microsoft Visual Studio for C++ there's a compiler switch `/clr:pure` or other flags (msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k8d11d4s.aspx).

When you use this mode, you will be able to use special markers to define that specific classes should be compiled as CLR managed classes. If you take care and write everything properly, /clr:pure will emit a normal 100%-managed assembly. I'm tempted to say "everything as if in C#" but that's not true, generated code will be different, but nevertheless, everything will work, metadata will be there, etc. ILSpy will decompile that just like any assembly generated by C#, VB.Net or F#, but probably the code/names/etc will be a bit more mangled.

Sidenote: If you invest in some real decompiler like Reflector, they can often take a C# assembly and decompile it as-if-written-in-managed-C++ and vice versa..

Furthermore, if you don't care about "pure" msil, you can even mix native and managed code. Half of the code in native C++, other half in managed, just take some care regarding pointers and references and cleanups, and compiler will happily emit for you a mixed assembly - here I have no idea if ILSpy will manage to show you anything. Probably it will show you the managed part and show the native part as being there but as not-disassemble-able.

Finally, it's also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-build-a-multifile-assembly which ILSpy probably also supports.